# MoviePy can't resize ImageClip

Tags: python, image, resize, moviepy

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from PIL import Image

image = ImageClip('2.jpg' )
resized_image = image.resize((400, 400),Image.LANCZOS)  
resized_image.save_frame('resized_image.jpg')
```

**Error**

```
resized_pil = pilim.resize(newsize[::-1], Image.ANTIALIAS)
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'
```

even using Image.LANCZOS its still finding Image.ANTIALIAS

Answer (score 0):

Try change the version of pillow library to 9.5.0

```
pip install Pillow==9.5.0
```

Comment: sorry for not giving back-ground details but I'm already on 9.5.0